# i'm unable to insert the date in My SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
import java.sql.*;


public class student extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form student
     */
    public student() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
        jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setText("jCheckBoxMenuItem1");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Name :");

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Roll :");

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Address");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jLabel4.setText("Gender");

        jRadioButton1.setText("Male");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setText("Female");
        jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31" }));

        jLabel5.setText("DOB:");

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" }));

        jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001" }));

        jButton2.setText("SUBMIT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("CANCEL");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                .addComponent(jButton3)))
                        .addContainerGap(161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 192, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("Hello");
        String name=jTextField1.getText();
        String roll=jTextField2.getText();
        String address=jTextArea1.getText();
        String gender="";
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
        gender=jRadioButton1.getText();
        }
        if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
        gender=jRadioButton2.getText();
        }
        String day=(String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String month=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
        String year=(String)jComboBox3.getSelectedItem();
        String dob=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
        //java.sql.Date dt=(java.sql.Date)dob;
        //java.sql.Date  sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        //System.out.println(dt);
        try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                //System.out.println("Loaded driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","");
        //System.out.println("Connected to DB");
        Statement st= conn.createStatement();
        String query="insert into student values('"+name+"',"+roll+",'"+address+"','"+gender+"',"+dob+")";
                System.out.println(query);
                st.executeUpdate(query);}
        catch(Exception e){
       //System.out.println("database");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(student.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new student().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

How can i insert the date entered in combox to mysql database

Comment: Use a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which will allow you to specify the type begin inserted.  Also, you may need to create a `java.sql.Date` to support it

Comment: Do you get any error/exception output, what is the problem ?

Comment: Add jdbc code and do it. Share the progress and challenges you come across doing it.

Comment: are you getting any exception

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` (`connection.prepareStatement();`) and set the parameter individually then execute the statement. This will also protect you against SQL injection: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: The error was missing quotes on the date; but I concur: go for PreparedStatement, for security, for escaping single quotes, backslashes (SQL syntax errors), conversion. MySQL has its own driver instead of the JDBC/ODBC bridge. Would recommend that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Using Normal Statement**

```
    try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root", "");
            Statement st= conn.createStatement();
// suppose name,roll,gender,dob are field in which u need the datas to be inserted
            String query="insert into student (name,roll,gender,dob) values('"+name+"','"+roll+"','"+address+"','"+gender+"','"+dob+"')";
            System.out.println(query);
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            st.close();
            conn.close();
          }
            catch(Exception e){
           //System.out.println("database");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Using PreparedStatement** (prevents SQL Injection)

```
      try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root", "");
// suppose name,roll,gender,dob are field in which u need the datas to be inserted
                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into student (name,roll,gender,dob) values(?,?,?,?)");
                st.setString(1, name);
                st.setString(2, roll);
                st.setString(3, gender);
                st.setDate(4, dob);
                st.executeUpdate();
                st.close();
                conn.close();
              }
                catch(Exception e){
               //System.out.println("database");
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Also Don't forget to add **[mysql.ja](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqljar.htm)r**

Comment: This is a perfect code for SQL injection: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png. The use of a `PreparedStatement` is much more recommended

Comment: Try inserting like for example insert into table (datefield) value  (MONTHNAME(yourdate))